# Copy multiple columns to another worksheet

Tags: xml, excel, vbc, vba

I have XML feed which has lot of unnecessary data, so I found following macro to copy rows, which include "Soccer" in column BA, to new worksheet
What I'd like it to do is to copy only specifics columns E,I,P,T,W,Y,Z to sheet not whole rows, so then I don't have to hide those unnecessary columns.

Sub SearchForString()

```
Dim LSearchRow As Integer
Dim LCopyToRow As Integer

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

'Start search in row 3
LSearchRow = 3

'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
LCopyToRow = 2

While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

    'If value in column BA = "Soccer", copy entire row to Sheet2
    If Range("BA" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Soccer" Then

        'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
        Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        'Move counter to next row
        LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

        'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    End If

    LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

Wend

'Position on cell A3
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A3").Select

MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a PivotTable instead. Add the E,I,P,T,W,Y,Z columns as columns in the PivotTable and add a Pivot filter by "Soccer".

Comment: that sounds like good idea, I've no experience with pivot tables, so I wouldn't thought of it. I'll give it a try and see if I can get it working. thanks a mil